# Unable to read environment variables

Tags: php, symfony, phpdotenv

I have a simple Symfony project, using `"symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",` in the `composer.json` and trying to read in the value of an environment variable.

This is my command:

```
var_dump($_ENV['MY_NEW_VAR']);
```

This is my `.env` file

```
MY_NEW_VAR=testing
```

Upon executing the command I get the following

```
string(7) "testing"
```

All good so far.... But now if I want to use environment variables to override the setting it returns an error. First I set the environment variable

```
export MY_NEW_VAR="something_else"
```

Then execute the command again, with the following results

```
[ErrorException]
Notice: Undefined index: MY_NEW_VAR
```

If I remove the environment variable using `unset MY_NEW_VAR` and execute the command again I get the value from the `.env` file

I would expect the environment variable to override the `.env` setting as explained in the comments of the `.env` file

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the later taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
```

Why does it not work with environment variables? Am I missing something?

Comment: OK that yields some strange results ... `getenv()` returns `false` when only using `.env` where as `$_SERVER` returns correct result. When using the environment variable `getenv()` and `$_SERVER` return `something_else` but `$_ENV` returns the error. So `$_SERVER` works in all cases, `getenv()` works only when environment variable is set and `$_ENV` works only when using `.env` file ...

Comment: `variables_order => GPCS => GPCS` - installed php using homebrew and never heard of this setting ... im guessing i need an E in there somewhere ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer though - going to set an E and try again ...

Comment: I set EGPCS and `$_ENV` started working - `getenv()` still returns `false` when only using the `.env`. Thanks for your help. If you write that as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question is correct, so I'd wager the problem lies somewhere else.

There are many vagaries and inconsistencies about how `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` work. I have found `$_SERVER` to be more reliable in my experience, and many times it safer to check both. E.g. if you check the code on `config/bootstrap.php` for Symfony 4.3 you'll see stuff like this:

```php
$_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = $_ENV['APP_ENV'] = ($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? $_ENV['APP_ENV'] ?? null) ?: 'dev';
```

In any case, if your `$_ENV` superglobal is initially empty, it could be because on the `variables_order` [setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order). Check its value, and if doesn't include an `E`, prepend it to the existing value and with that it should be populated correctly.

The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) say that `S` is equivalent to `ES`...

> In both the CGI and FastCGI SAPIs, $_SERVER is also populated by values from the environment; S is always equivalent to ES regardless of the placement of E elsewhere in this directive.

but I have not found it to be consistently so.